# How to use Stringvar - Tkinter for multiple entries and tracing those multiple entries

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to build GUI using tkinter for displaying csv file data and trying to add few columns which has manual entries,

But I am stuck at how to use StringVar for multiple entries and use trace method to apply changes when user update some value.

I tried to do many things using examples I found online but did not abel to do it.

I am able to create multiple stringvar but can't update it's value and when user enter something in entry widget and also I want to trace those stringvar object,

here is the code I wrote,

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from tkinter import ttk

entries = {}

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Saurabh\Desktop\Python\New folder\abc.csv')
df['Symbol'].replace('  ', np.nan, inplace=True)
df= df.dropna(subset=['Symbol'])

def search():
    for (name,var) in entries.items():   
        print(f"{name}: {var.get()}")
   

f2 = tk.Tk()

for ind in df.index:
    var = tk.StringVar()
    entries[ind] = var
    entry = ttk.Entry(f2 ,textvariable = var,width=25).grid(row=ind,column=2)

   
but = ttk.Button(f2,text="search",command=search())
but.grid(row=0,column=3)

f2.mainloop()
```

kindly help

Comment: It doesn't look like you're even trying to trace the updates to the variables. Have you tried using the `trace` methods?

Comment: hi @Bryan I did try it , tried many things by seeing lot of posts but not abel to figure it out an I am able to do it for one row but when it comes to multiple rows and entries I am just going blank and all those posts helped me but still stuck at here

Comment: thanks @toyota  it worked. it was such a dumb mistake. :/ couldn't found it for one week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove brace bracket.

Change this:

```
but = ttk.Button(f2,text="search",command=search())
```

to:

```
 but = ttk.Button(f2,text="search",command=search)
```